# Redirecting to legacy action from Struts 2 action?

Tags: java, url, parameters, struts2, actionresult

I have Struts 2 action named as `CustomerAction.java` which is under  `folderHierarchy/actions/customer`(`customer` is `namespace` here). From one of the method inside this action class, I am redirecting to my legacy action class

**`Result` Mapping is:**

```
@Result(name = "redirectTo", location = "#parameters.redirectLocation", type = "redirect") })
```

where value of `#parameters.redirectLocation` is

`/customerhome.do?custIdId=200`

**`Action` method is :**

```
 @Action(value = "CustomerAction!redirectToPage")
  public String redirectToLocation() {
    return "redirectTo";
  }
```

But issue is struts automatically adding current action namespace(i.e `customer`) before redirection location.

So instead of redirecting to

`/myWebApp/customerhome.do?custIdId=200`,

Struts 2 is redirecting to

`/myWebApp/customer/customerhome.do?custIdId=200`

I am not getting why it's adding `customer` namespace and how to get rid of this?

I've also tried:

```
@Result(name = "redirectTo", location = "#parameters.redirectTo", type = "redirect", params = { "namespace", "/" }) })
```

but it did not work too.

**Another observation is:**

**what works:**

```
@Result(name = ComposeMessageCrudAction.REDIRECT_TO, location = "/customerhome.do?custIdId=200", type = "redirect") })
```

**what does not work:**

```
@Result(name = "redirectTo", location = "#parameters.redirectLocation", type = "redirect") })
```

where value of `#parameters.redirectLocation`  is

`/customerhome.do?custIdId=200`

I am not getting why second approach is not working and why its adding `customer` namespace before

`/customerhome.do?custIdId=200`

Answer (score 0):

Use the value of `location` attribute as a dynamic parameter to the struts result.

```
private String redirectLocation = "/customerhome.do?custIdId=200";

public String getRedirectLocation() {
  return redirectLocation;
}

@Result(name = REDIRECT_TO, location = "${redirectLocation}", type = "redirect")
```

Comment: As i said in my post, i have already tried dynamic parameter @Result(name = "REDIRECT_TO", location = "#parameters.redirectLocation", type = "redirect") . Also tried your way but no help. Still it adds namespace
 
 @Result(name = "REDIRECT_TO", location = "${redirectLocation}", type = "redirect")